# I have written a program to print the digits of a number in reverse order. It gives me ArrayIndexOutOfBound exception

Tags: java

I have written the following program to print a number in the reverse order.
It is giving me an ArrayIndexOutOfBound exception

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Ch6_26 {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int x;

        System.out.println("Enter the number to be reversed: ");
        x = input.nextInt();
        Reverse(x);

    }

    static void Reverse(int a){
        int s[] = new int[5];
        int j = 0;
        int x = a;

        for(int i = 1; a >= 0 ; i++){
            s[i] = x % 10;
            x /= 10;
            j = i;
        }

        for(int i = 0; i <= j; i++){
            System.out.printf("%d  ", s[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is s[] made into an int[5]?  What is the biggest x will ever be?  Why does i start at 1 not 0?  Is 'j' really a good name for that variable?

Comment: Your for loop appears as if it would run forever, as it is checking if a >= 0, and a is not changed at all in the loop.

Comment: And ... you should debug that. It means you're accessing an index out of the bounds of your array.

Comment: Thanks everyone, i have tried with replacing a with x and still getting the same error. However, realised that the condition should have been x > 0 rather than x >= 0, since this is always going to be true and causing the index to fall out of bound.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try

```
for(int i = 0; x >= 0 && i<5 ; i++){
        s[i] = x % 10;
        x /= 10;
        j = i;
    }
```

and also keep in mind that this works for only numbers less than or equal to 5 digits

Answer (score 1):

In your for loop, your ending condition depends on `a` changing, but you don't change it:

```
for(int i = 1; *a* >= 0 ; i++){
    s[i] = x % 10;
    x /= 10;
    j = i;
    //a is not changed at all..?
}
```

so the for loop will never end, continuing on to i=5+, which throws an error because your array is not that big

Answer (score 1):

This is why it's going out of bounds:

```
for(int i = 1; a >= 0 ; i++){
```

`a >= 0` will always be true when `a` starts as being greater than or equal to 0 since you do not modify the value of `a` within the loop.  `s` always has a length of 5 but `i` just keeps on getting bigger.  Once `i` hits 5, it is out of bounds of the `s` array which only has a size of 5.

Answer (score 1):

What's the big use of the Array, why not you do simply this way :

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Reverse
{
    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int number = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println(reverseNumber(number));
    }

    private static int reverseNumber(int num)
    {
        int rev = 0;
        while (num > 0)
        {
            rev = rev * 10 + (num % 10);
            num /= 10;
        }

        return rev;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i have realized that the condition i have used is wrong by comparing from your post.

Comment: You're MOST WELCOME and KEEP SMILING :-). I was just wondering where exactly to put my answer, as a comment (which I could not because of the code involved), I wanted this to be a suggestion in actual terms. Glad you got it sorted though :-)